# React.js + PhoneGap App not rendering the images on Device

Tags: image, cordova, reactjs, device

I have a Hybrid Mobile Application developed using React.js and PhoneGap. The local images in the browser simulator are loading fine but when I install the Application on the device the images are not loaded. I tried below approaches but none of them load the image on device.

**1.**

```
import redcar from './RedCar.png'
<image src={redcar} />
```

**2.**

```
var redcar = require('./RedCar.png')
<image src={redcar} />
```

**3.**

```
<img src="./RedCar.png" />
```

**4.**
Copied image into android\assets folder and tried

```
<image src='/android_asset/www/RedCar.png' responsive />
```

**5.**
index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; img-src * filesystem: data:">
```

Only way it's rendering the images on the device is by giving a background image to div in css file. background-image: url("./RedCar.png");
But I need to read the image paths from JSON so we can't use this approach.

My **webpack.config.js** looks like this

```
module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          enforce: 'pre',
        },
        { test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
            plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
          }
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' },
        { test: /(\.eot|\.woff2|\.woff|\.ttf|\.svg|\.png)/, loader: 'file-loader' },
        { test: /\.ya?ml$/, loader: 'json-loader!yaml-loader' },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=img/img-[hash:6].[ext]' }
        /*{ test: /\.html$/, loader: "html-loader" }*/
      ],
    }
```

I have attached the image of on target debugging, where that particular image shows error.[snapshot from device debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoYp8.png)

Any idea what's going wrong here ...

Comment: I'm struggling with the exact same thing. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this. If I manually enter the path in HTML it works, but when React creates an element with the same path the image isn't loaded.